# Static image not updating on website development and production

Tags: python, django, static

Static image not updating on website
Edit: FIXED! I forgot I had the old logo in realestatesite/realestatesite/static/img/logo.png and only copied it to `realestatesite/static/img` once I did `python manage.py collectstatic`. All I had to do was update it there and run the command again to fix it.

Original post:

I'm following this guide that shows how to edit the admin panel layout I added a logo for testing initially, but now I've deleted the old one and added the new one; it doesn't update on the site.

The old logo is gone, the new one has the exact same name and location.

```
.../templates/admin/base_site.html:

{%extends 'admin/base.html'%}
{%load static%}

{%block branding%}
<h1 id='head'>
  <img class='brand_img' src="{%static 'img/logo.png'%}" alt="Dynasty 8 Real Estate" height='50' width='80'>Admin Area
</h1>
{%endblock%}
```

I tried migrating, restarting, and clearing the cache.